# Karma not running Angular tests as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am new to Karma , so the error might be very basic.

It is my karma.conf.js file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/index.js',
      'app/heroDetail.js',
      'app/*.js',
      'test/*.js',
      'app/**/*.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Inside `app directory` my `js` and `html` files reside.

[image]

The `index.html` looks like :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-heroComponentSimple-production</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="heroDetail.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="heroApp">
  <!-- components match only elements -->
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Hero</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And `index.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
        this.hero = {
            name: 'Miles Bronson'
        };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

Now in my `test spec` file I tried :

```
describe('MainController',function(){
    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        controller;
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('heroApp');

        inject(function($injector){
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $injector.get('$controller')('MainCtrl',{$scope: $scope});
        });
    });

    it('should initialize name of the hero',function(){
        expect($scope.hero.name).toEqual('Miles Bronson'); 
    });

    it('should not pass',function(){
        expect($scope.hero.name).toEqual('Milesl Bronsonkk'); 
    });
});
```

Now when I do `karma start karma.conf.js` it says

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js
18 01 2017 19:58:51.928:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
18 01 2017 19:58:51.943:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
18 01 2017 19:58:51.943:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
18 01 2017 19:58:51.953:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
18 01 2017 19:58:54.145:INFO [Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket oOKBdNiWr9pVmcqnAAAA with id 12481546
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) MainController should initialize name of the hero FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:45:27)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) MainController should not pass FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:49:27)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (2 FAILED) ERROR (0.052 secs / 0.038 secs)
```

**But the second one should have failed right while the first one should have passed ? Why is this unexpected behavior ?**

What am I doing wrong ?

The chrome browser also does not help much ...

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Try console.log($scope.hero) - this should print out an object, right?

Comment: Both expectations should fail - you are comparing a string `'$scope.hero.name'` to `'Miles Bronson'` and `'Milesl Bronsonkk'`.

Comment: @alecxe .. ok got it . But even after fixing it , it says ` Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.017 secs / 0.002 secs)`. ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder are you sure you are executing and editing and showing us the same exact test?

Comment: @alecxe .. Now I am getting a different error. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Have a look at how this [example](https://gist.github.com/bbraithwaite/d69d3e68b004bc0d3318) works. Specifically lines 25-31. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you've got a nesting problem and one too many describes...

Looks like you want something more like this, where the beforeEach fires before each test:

```
describe('MainController',function(){
    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        controller;
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('heroApp');

        inject(function($injector){
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $injector.get('$controller')('MainCtrl',{$scope: $scope});
        });
    });

    it('should initialize name of the hero',function(){
        expect($scope.hero.name).toEqual('Miles Bronson'); 
    });

    it('should not pass',function(){
        expect($scope.hero.name).toEqual('Milesl Bronsonkk'); 
    });
});
```

Furthermore, you're not really using global scope in your controller... I think your test can be much simpler in setup and assertions. Something like:

```
describe('TestMainController',function(){
    beforeEach(module('heroApp'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
      $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('should initialize name of the hero',function(){
      var controller = $controller('MainController');
      expect(controller.hero.name).toEqual('Miles Bronson'); 
    });

    it('should not pass',function(){
      var controller = $controller('MainController');
      expect(controller.hero.name).toEqual('Milesl Bronsonkk'); 
    });
});
```

Here's a plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/IAs4iYL69E8Nm5uvQDw1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the response. But still it shows `Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.013 secs / 0.002 secs)`. It should execute 2 right ?

Comment: Yes, it should say 2 of 2... make sure you've got everything nested properly.

Comment: Thanks for resolving it ? But now another error comes . Could you please see the updated question ?

Comment: Well, you're not really using global $scope in your controller... something angular 1.5+ is getting away from. Updated answer to reflect.

Comment: Probably should not edit your questions like this also... this will be very confusing to future readers.